# configuring postfix wtih gmail

Tags: postfix

I have followed this tutorial to forward emails to my gmail account so that I can receive messages from people who contact me through the contact form of my website: https://easyengine.io/tutorials/linux/ubuntu-postfix-gmail-smtp/

But obviously when I reply to them, I use my gmail address and it does not feel professional.

I have found tutorials for configuring postfix so that I can create an email address like contact@my-domain.com. But since I don't have a mail client on my server, and it is not convenient to read emails on a server, I still want postfix to forward mails to my gmail account.

How would I then configure postfix/gmail so that when I reply to emails, gmail uses the contact@my-domain.com address instead of my gmail address ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you follow the advice on the gmail support page? [Send mail from a different address or alias](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/22370?hl=en)